# Apache 2.4 mpm_winnt: one thread takes all resources

Tags: apache-2.4, threads, multi-threading

I am working with Apache 2.4.33x64 on Server 2008 to run a site for max. 15 users. On the site you can do some really expensive calculations which can take some minutes (an external script is called).
During these calculations the server is on 15% CPU and roughly on the same RAM usage than without (12% of 16GB). However another user can't use the site until the calculations are finished.
The config file is more or less default, so the server should run on mpm_winnt.

Are there settings in mpm_winnt that would allow that an additional thread can work even if the first is busy? Or does it make sense to choose a different multi-processing module?

In the documentation for mpm_winnt I couldn't find something useful.
The default ThreadsPerChild = 64 should not be a problem, should it? The only thing I tried to change was setting the MaxMemFree directive to a higher value which was not helpful.